# Angular 5 filter multiple columns

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a custom pipe to filter my *ngFor loop using an input field with ngModel. With my other custom pipe (sortBy), it works perfectly fine. However, the filter pipe seems to make it that none of the data appears. I'm still learning this, and I tried a few variations to no avail

```
<table class="table table-sm table hover border-bottom-1">
<thead class="thead-light">
<th scope="col" *ngFor="let column of columns" [ngClass]="{hide: !column.active}">
<input *ngif="hideFilters" class="px-2 w-100">
<tr>
<th scope ="col"
*ngFor ="let column of columns"
[ngClass] ="{hide: !column.active}"
>{{column.value}}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor ="let value of values"(click)="editvalue(value)">
<td 
class="text-truncate"
*ngFor="let column of columns"
[ngClass]="{hide:column.active}"
>{{value[column.section][column.key]}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

//I need help
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit vague. Can you post the pipe code and what you are trying to achieve? What you can try is to put the pipe on the ngFor itself like this `*ngFor ="let column of columns | sortBy`